# Filtered rows stop the filling of my listbox

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to fill a listbox in VBA from a filtered table.
Here is the code:

```
Dim rng as range
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("mysheet").Range("mytable").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
With lstDetails
.List = rng.Cells.Value
End with
```

lstDetails is my listbox.
Problem is that at the filling of the listbox stops as soon as there is one hidden (filtered) record.

Any clue what to do?

Regards,
Jonatan

Comment: Does the ListBox have column headers ?

Comment: @CDP1802 yes it does

Comment: Would it be feasible to copy the filtered range to another sheet (can be hidden) and set the `Listbox.rowsource = sheets("hidden").usedrange.address`

Comment: Will give it a try and let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Copy visible cells to another sheet to get a contiguous range.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim rng As Range, tbl As Range
    lstDetails.RowSource = ""
    
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Sheets("hidden").UsedRange.Clear
        Set tbl = .Sheets("mysheet").ListObjects("mytable").Range
        tbl.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy .Sheets("hidden").Range("A1")
        Set rng = .Sheets("hidden").UsedRange
        Set rng = rng.Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1)
    End With
    
    With lstDetails
        .Clear
        .ColumnHeads = True
        .RowSource = "hidden!" & rng.Address
    End With
    
End Sub
```